# 400 bad request for first get request

Tags: python, http

After login to the webpage. First time I'm getting 400 bad request error and after refreshing the page it is loading correctly.
Not able to find the issue because I'm passing the same url both the times.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not sure how you expect us to help without seeing the code OR the url...